# Physical characteristics of Murthi in Tirumala?

Tags: venkateshwara

Good day.

What are the physical characteristics of the Murthi in Venkateswara Temple, Tirumala that is similar to other gods such as Shiva, Shakti, Vishnu, Surya, Skanda and Ganapati.

For example, some say that kati and varada hastam represent Skanda.

I need this information for an article that I'm preparing.

Thanks

Comment: You can find the physical description here - https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.162281  Please check the table of contents page.

Comment: The author of the book was a former chairman of TTD for nearly a year.

Comment: Thanks for the info